# Switching between CultureInfo in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# . I am trying to parse a csv file with `Datatype.tryParse()` .However The time stamp is changing across the csv file. Part of the file is DD/MM/YY and the other part is MM/DD/YY.
How can I switch between the two formats?
How to make the cultureInfo valid for the two formats ?

`DateTime.TryParse(timeStamp, cultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, outputDate) ;`

Comment: How would you know which matches `dd/MM/yy` or `MM/dd/yy` if the supplied value is `01/01/18`?

Comment: You have to tell it which one to use when. Otherwise, how will it know if 10/11/20 is November 10 or October 11?

Comment: You can't have one format that handles both. Do you know in advance what format a particular line uses?

Comment: Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: After a certain line the whole format is changed

Comment: How do you know which line?

Answer (score -1):

There is also an alternative method `TryParseExact` where you can define the format of the date you want to parse explicitely. Check the docs for more information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Not seeing how this helps for `1/2/2020`?